# OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager exception

Tags: .net, oracle

We tried to connect to Oracle DB by using tns entry but the connection returns a timeout.

**The source code:**

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("conn"))) {
  connection.Open();

  OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();

}
```

**The response:**

> at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)\r\n   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)\r\n   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString
> cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword,
> SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection
> connRefForCriteria)\r\n   at
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()\r\n   at
> ToolMaterial.Controllers.Admin.MaterialDrawingController.grabASapData()

**appsetting**

```
"Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =   )(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER =DEDICATED )(SERVICE_NAME =  ))); User Id =  ; Password = ;
```

Comment: Did you find the issue with the above?  I am doing the same but getting an "index outside the bounds of the array" when trying to open the connection.  This is connecting to an old 8i instance